# how to open API services call to a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to open the API service call to a new window tab but tried to use **window.open()** and it doesn't work. I also tried to put the **ng-href="URLwithParam" in the HTMLtemplate with target="_blank"**. I'm a newbie in angular and html. Please help me

```
define(['directives/directives'],
function (directives) {
    directives.directive('directiveFeeReport', ['reportServices', function (reportServices) {

        var prmCompanyId;
        var prmDateTranFrom;
        var formattedPrmDateTranFrom;
        var prmDateTranTo;
        var formattedPrmDateTranTo;
        var urlLink = "http://localhost:8080/sdimngapi/np_feereport/feeReportGenerate/";
        var teststring;

        function feeReportController( $stateParams, notification) {
            this.roleId = $stateParams.id;
            // notification is the service used to display notifications on the top of the screen
            this.notification = notification;


        };

        feeReportController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'notification'];

        function init(scope, element, $stateParams, $window, $http) {

            scope.generateFeeReport = function() {

                 prmCompanyId = scope.companyId;
                 prmDateTranFrom = new Date(scope.dateTranFrom);
                 formattedPrmDateTranFrom = prmDateTranFrom.getFullYear() + '-' + (prmDateTranFrom.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + prmDateTranFrom.getDate();
                 prmDateTranTo = scope.dateTranTo;
                 formattedPrmDateTranTo = prmDateTranTo.getFullYear() + '-' + (prmDateTranTo.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + prmDateTranTo.getDate();

                // I TRY TO OPEN THE Service API calls to new window here.
                //window.open('/theURL', '_blank');

                // API Calls
                reportServices.GetFeeReport(prmCompanyId, formattedPrmDateTranFrom, formattedPrmDateTranTo, function (res) {
                     //console.log(res);
                })

            });
        };

        //#region HTML Template
        var feeReportTemplate = '<div class="modal-body">' + 
                                    '<div class="page-header">' +
                                        '<ma-view-actions><ma-back-button></ma-back-button></ma-view-actions>' +
                                        '<h1>Generate Fee Report</h1>' +
                                    '</div>' +

                                    '<div class="row flex-row">' + 
                                        '<div class="col-md-5 form-group">' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-4"><label>Company : </label></div>' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" size="10" ng-model="companyId" class="form-control" placeholder="Company ID"/></div>' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-4"><label>Date From : </label></div>' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-5"><input type="date" size="10" ng-model="dateTranFrom" class="form-control" placeholder="Date From"/></div>' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-4"><label>Date To : </label></div>' +
                                            '<div class="col-md-5"><input type="date" size="10" ng-model="dateTranTo" class="form-control" placeholder="Date To"/></div>' +

                                            '<div class="col-lg-5"><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="generateFeeReport()">Send</a></div>' +

                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>';

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: init,
            controller: feeReportController,
            controllerAs: 'controller',
            template: feeReportTemplate
        };
    } ]);
});
```